# Expanding a differential equation in powers of $\epsilon$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

How does one expand the right hand side of

$$\frac{da}{d\theta}=\frac{\epsilon h\sin(\theta)}{1+\epsilon a^{-1}h\cos(\theta)}$$

in powers of $\epsilon$ and obtain

$$\frac{da}{d\theta}=\epsilon h\sin(\theta)+O(\epsilon^{2})?$$

*Note:* For brevity, $h$ stands for $h(a\cos(\theta), a\sin(\theta))$ and $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, i.e., $|\epsilon|\ll 1$.

*Context:* I am trying to work along with the textbook *Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations* by Jordan and Smith and came across this step in section 4.2 *Amplitude and frequency estimates: polar coordinates*. We are looking at a differential equation in the form

$$\ddot{x} + \epsilon h(x,\dot{x})+x = 0, $$

which has an equivalent system

$$\dot{x}=y, \dot{y}=-\epsilon h(x,y)-x. $$

The system itself can be represented parametrically by time-dependent polar coordinates $a(t), \theta(t)$ which allows the polar form of the system

$$\dot{a}=-\epsilon h\sin(\theta)$$

$$\dot{\theta}=-1-\epsilon a^{-1}hcos(\theta).$$

The goal is to eventually derive some estimates for the amplitude and frequency of the periodic time solutions of $\ddot{x} + \epsilon h(x,\dot{x})+x = 0$, if any, which are represented by closed paths on its corresponding phase diagram.

Comment: I'm guessing on your $h;$ was it using arc trig functions?

Comment: @AdrianKeister : This was just inserting the polar coordinates $(x,\dot x)=(a\cos θ,a\sin θ)$ into $h$, the inverse functions would be strange at that place.

Comment: The formula for $\dot θ$ is wrong. It should be $$\dot θ=\frac{x\dot y-\dot x y}{x^2+y^2 }=-1+\frac{x\ddot x+x^2}{a^2 }=-1-ha^{-1}\cosθ.$$

Comment: **HINT**: Use $\dfrac 1{1-x} = 1+x+o(x)$ for $x\approx 0$.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, yes, you are correct. Thank you.

Comment: @TedShifrin Definitely. I didn't see that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{da}{d\theta}=\dfrac{\epsilon h\sin\theta}{1+\epsilon a^{-1}h\cos\theta}$

$(a\epsilon h\sin\theta)\dfrac{d\theta}{da}=a+\epsilon h\cos\theta$

$-a\epsilon h\dfrac{d(\cos\theta)}{da}=a+\epsilon h\cos\theta$

$-a\epsilon h\dfrac{du}{da}=a+\epsilon hu$ by letting $u=\cos\theta$

$\dfrac{du}{da}+\dfrac{u}{a}=-\dfrac{1}{\epsilon h}$

$\dfrac{d(au)}{da}=-\dfrac{a}{\epsilon h}$

$au=C-\dfrac{a^2}{2\epsilon h}$

$\cos\theta=\dfrac{C}{a}-\dfrac{a}{2\epsilon h}$

Comment: If you read the question again closely, you will find that $h=h(x,\dot x)=h(a\cosθ,a\sinθ)$ is not a constant. If it were a constant, then the original equation $\ddot x+ϵh+x=0$ would be easy to solve as a linear DE.